# How to connect Azure Sql with google looker data studio?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, looker-studio

I am trying to connect Azure SQL Database to Google Looker Studio. I have tried using Microsoft SQL Server data source and I'm getting an error that I can't understand or search.

> Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your
> request.
>
> Error ID: b723485e

The next option is to try and Enable SSL but it's asking for a certificate. I'm not sure where to get this certificate from?

I am also not sure if Microsoft SQL Server is the right connection as it says its for SQL Server 2018 and I know Azure SQL is different. I have successfully connected using the third party source called "SQL" but this is a paid service and my client doesn't want to use a third party. Any suggestions on how to connect?

Comment: You can find more information on this blog https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/certificate-based-authentication-for-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3109938